# Mysql: ER_PARSE_ERROR: while sending create procedure code from node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures, escaping

I am trying to send create procedure query from node js to MYSQL. 
I am reading Mysql.proc table to get the stored procedure definitions.

Mysql code working fine when submitting from mysql client like workbench or hedis

Getting following error while submitting code from NodeJS

```
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE `qwe`.`USP_GET_ALL_STOCK_WITH_INDICATORS`( IN `IPV_DATE` DATE )' at line 1
    .
    .
    .
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage:
   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'CREATE PROCEDURE `qwe`.`USP_GET_ALL_STOCK_WITH_INDICATORS`( IN `IPV_DATE` DATE )\' at line 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql:
   'USE qwe;    CREATE PROCEDURE `qwe`.`USP_GET_ALL_STOCK_WITH_INDICATORS`( IN `IPV_DATE` DATE )BEGIN IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM StockCandle where `DATE`=IPV_DATE) THEN SET @D:=(SELECT MAX(`DATE`) FROM StockCandle); ELSE SET @D:=IPV_DATE; END IF; -- select @D; SELECT  SM.Symbol, SM.MA13, SM.MA8, SM.MA5, CASE WHEN SM.MA5>SM.MA8 AND SM.MA8>MA13 THEN \'>>>\' WHEN SM.MA5<SM.MA8 AND SM.MA8<MA13 THEN \'<<<\' ELSE NULL
END ALLIGATOR ,SM.RSI, SM.BHAVTIME, SM.CANDLEINDICATOR FROM StockMaster SM  where SM.DATE=@D; END // ' }
```

tried below code to pares sql in node

```
formattdSQL = formattdSQL.replace(/(?:\\[rtn]|[\r\t]+)+/g, ' ');
```

Query to get procedure

```
SELECT `name`, CONVERT(param_list USING utf8), CONVERT(body USING utf8)
INTO @spname, @spparams, @spbody
FROM mysql.proc WHERE `name` = 'USP_GET_ALL_STOCK_WITH_INDICATORS' AND db = v_oldDB;
SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, '\r\n', 'DELIMITER //','\r\n','CREATE PROCEDURE `', v_newDB, '`.`', @spname, '`(', @spparams,')',@spbody, ' //', '\r\n','');
```

I expect that create procedure query should be executed successfully from node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DELIMITER` directive is not part of MySQL *Server* SQL.  That is used only with interactive *client* utilities that parse an input stream or the contents of an on-screen text box into individual statements -- like workbench or (presumably) "hedis" (whatever that may be).

You don't use it when you are using a programming library to send a query.

Just send the procedure declaration as a single query.  Send the `USE` statement as a separate query, before that.

First query:

```
USE qwe
```

(A trailing semicolon in the first query is not actually expected by the server but is allowed if you send it.)

Second query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
...
END
```

There should be no `DELIMITER //` before, nor `//` after.  Those are all client-side constructs, not meaningful to the server.

There is no need to use your `formattdSQL.replace(...)` statement to remove newlines.  That only serves to make your code unreadable, and isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you @Michael removing USE DB worked, I need to send 100 of sprc definition in one go, What delimiter i should use at end of each proc definition? Right now i m able to send single proc only.

Comment: You *might* be able to set `multipleStatements: true` in the connection options and then use a `;` but that option is an exceptionally bad idea because it makes certain SQL injection vulnerabilities possible that are not possible by default.  If you turn on your MySQL server general query log, you'll find that workbench, *et al,* do not send multiple queries at a time.  Each proc definition will be sent as an individual query.